# WPF ListView - how to add items programmatically?

Tags: wpf, listview, listviewitem, populate

Even if I know it's not ideal - I need to programmatically populate a listView (for whatever reason).

I am declaring my columns in the markup:

```
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Value}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
```

I am adding the items like this in code (it's obviously in a loop):

```
            MyData data = getDataItem(index); //< -- whatever
            ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
            item.DataContext = data;
            this.myListView.Items.Add(item);
```

Where MyData is defined as:

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

The items are being added (I can see the rows) but I don't see any content.

Anyone any clue?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It works changing the code to:

```
        MyData data = getDataItem(index); //< -- whatever
        this.myListView.Items.Add(data);
```

Now it looks obvious but ... go figure!

Comment: Do you also happen to know how to solve the same issue, having a general list, that can take different objects, with different properties?

Comment: WOw another Persie fan here OR Persie can code! :)
anyways, thx @RobinVanPersi

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MyData> yourList= new List<MyData>();
//adding elements to yourList (...)


foreach (MyData m in yourList)
{
    myListView.Items.Add(m);
}
```

Comment: Who voted this down, rather: why??? This seems a useful answer. I'd like to learn