# Add SubItems to ListView without using XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, listviewitem

How do you add sub-items to a `ListView`? I need to generate everything dynamically, but every example I've found uses XAML.

Non-WPF was so simple:

```
ListViewItem lvi = listview.items.add(wahtever);
lvi. blah blah blah
```

How do you add sub-items in WPF without using XAML?

Comment: The WPF listview dont have 'subitems' like the old winforms does. It requires a very different mindset. I thought exactly the way you are now, What the hell is with all the XAML? Winforms so much more straight forward. But now, I cant go back to winforms. WPF wins in my book hands down. Just takes a bit of time to get your head around it but when you do. It's awesome.

Comment: Yep I remember my first few months with WPF ... my baldness increased... Now any UI platform I think about, I want it to have Bindings, Themes, Styles, Triggers, DataContexts, Commands, Attached Properties. Damn WinForms are so lame! :p

Answer (score 8):

As already mentioned, WPF doesn't have sub-items like WinForms.  Instead you use properties on an object that suits your purposes.

For completeness, here is XAML contrasted with code.

XAML:

```
    <UniformGrid Columns="2">
        <ListView Name="xamlListView">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="X Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding X}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Y Value" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Y}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.Items>
                <PointCollection>
                    <Point X="10" Y="20"/>
                    <Point X="20" Y="30"/>
                </PointCollection>
            </ListView.Items>
        </ListView>
        <ListView Name="codeListView"/>
    </UniformGrid>
```

Code:

```
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var view = new GridView();
        view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = "First Name", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("First") });
        view.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn { Header = "Last Name", DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Last") });
        codeListView.View = view;
        codeListView.Items.Add(new { First = "Bill", Last = "Smith" });
        codeListView.Items.Add(new { First = "Jane", Last = "Doe" });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  That did the trick.  So now it seems that with everything you use the binding even through code?  Interesting and frustrating change, but I thank you so much for your help as it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

The "WPF way" would be to bind your listview to a collection that represents the data you want to display. Then add objects containing **data** to that collection. You almost never should have to deal with adding `ListViewItems` to your list manually as you are planning to do. I could come up with an example but there's many threads here on SO already that solve exactly this problem:

1. [Add programmatically ListViewItem to Listview in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665234/add-programmatically-listviewitem-to-listview-in-wpf)
2. [WPF ListView - how to add items programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305406/wpf-listview-how-to-add-items-programmatically)

Comment: I need one favor, How can i change the background color by add rows dynamically as above?

Answer (score -3):

SubItem or ListItem??
Easy:

```
myListbox.Items.Add(object);
```

You can add any type of object into that collection or a specific ListBoxItem object like this one:

```
this.List.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem{ Content = "Value to display"});
```