# How to Add Subitems to Listview in WPF and this subitems Dynamically through programming?

Tags: c#, wpf

How to add Subitem to listview programmatically.
want to add dynamically items to listview.
Below is the secnario.

```
   listView1.Items.Add(new Datalist()
            {
                clinicid = "Clinic ID",
                if (chkdate.IsChecked == true)
                listView1.Items.Add(new Datalist() { Date = "Date" });

            });
```

[image]

Comment: Is the above code not working? what is the error?

Comment: Problem is i try alot to add a subitem to listView on the base of checkboxcontrol checked and new Column is added to listview and i want to add a subitems element to listview which contain data which is retrive from database.

Comment: I want to code like this to working in WPF this Code work in Window Form but in WPF its not working.<br/>ListView1.Items.Add(new { ClinicID = "123",if(chkname.IsChecked == true){ Name = "Khalid"}, if(chkgender.IsChecked == true) { Gender = "Male" }});

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF ListView Subitems without XAML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687184/add-subitems-to-listview-without-using-xaml).

Comment: WPF listview dont have 'subitems' like the old winforms does

Comment: use List<string> li  = new List<string>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
ListView1.Items.Add(new 
{
   ClinicID = "123",
   Name = chkname.IsChecked ? "Khalid" : string.Empty,
   Gender = chkgender.IsChecked ? "Male" : string.Empty
});
```

Comment: ListView1.Items.Add(new { ClinicID = "123",if(chkname.IsChecked == true){ Name = "Khalid"}, if(chkgender.IsChecked == true) { Gender = "Male" }});

Comment: @Khalid, yeah you can't have sub-brackets in an object constructor like that. I changed it to what should compile given your desires.