# Insert new item into WPF listbox before the old items

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

how i can Insert new item into WPF listbox before the old items

like `old text` then i add

```
new text 

old text
```

instead

```
old text 

new text
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/665234/add-programmatically-listviewitem-to-listview-in-wpf

Comment: Is the Listbox databound, or you want to create a ListBoxItem programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ListBox.Items.Insert(0, "Message");
```

something like this?